# How is, in this example, G isomorphic to a subgroup T in A(S)?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm pursuing my first introductory course in Algebra right now, and the book I'm using is Topics in Algebra by I.N. Herstein. In a segment about group theory he talks about applications of the fact that a finite group 'G' can't be simple if it has a subgroup 'H' such that order of G ie. o(G) is not divisible by the factorial of the index of H ie. i(H)!

Now the application he discusses is in terms of an example that goes like this:

Let G be a non-abelian group of order 6. We know that there is an 'a' in the group such that a^2=e where e is the identity element of the group. Consider the subgroup H= {a,e} which is of order 2 and index 3 w.r.t G. Suppose, we know H is not normal in G (he later proves that and that's okay). Since H has only itself and (e) as it's subgroups, thus it doesn't have any normal subgroups of G in it.

NOW COME THE PARTS I DON'T GET.

1. He says "Thus G is isomorphic to a subgroup T of A(S) where S is the set of right cosets of H in G". How did he conclude that?
2. "Since o(A(S))=i(H)!=3!=6, T=S and G is isomorphic to A(S)=S3".  I did not get most of that too, how is order of o(A(S)) equal to 6 and even if it is, suppose we were considering a general scenario, what does that imply?

Could someone please help me understand this better? And also, what does this application exactly "apply"? In a more general sense?

Comment: You can get the homomorphism into $A(S)$, which I assume is the automorphism group on that set, through the group action of $G$ on $S$ by left translation.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is this : If $G$ is a group, and $H< G$, you can let $G$ *act* on $S:= G/H$ (these are just the left cosets of $H$ in $G$ - it is not a group) by left multiplication :
$$
(g, xH) \mapsto gxH
$$
Alternatively, for each $g\in G$, you can define
$$
\sigma_g : S \to S \text{ by } xH \to gxH
$$
This $\sigma_g$ is a permutation of $G/H$, and the map
$$
f:G\to A(S), \text{ given by } g \mapsto \sigma_g
$$
is a homomorphism.

Now the kernel of this homomorphism is contained in $H$. In this case, since $H$ is not normal in $G$, the only option for this kernel is $\{e\}$. In other words, $f$ is injective.

This will help you answer both your questions.